# Automatizing a regression function

Tags: r, regression, paste

I have a list:

```
elscincarticles <- c("total_info_inst_org_plan", "total_info_relev_jurid", "total_info_eco_pres_est", "total_art_portal", "total_onze")
```

and a variable

```
group_var <- c("Tramspoblacio")
```

I want to do a function that makes a regression for those two vectors, taking each of "elscincarticles" as dependent variable and the different levels of "group_var" as independent variable.

To avoid repetition, I have written this. First, the list and then I paste the regression

```
regression <- data_frame(
  formula = elscincarticles, paste('~ "Tramspoblacio'), 
  model = map(
    .x = formula, 
    .f = function(x) lm(x, data = index_articles))
)
```

However, it does not work and I get the following message:

```
Error in `map()`:
i In index: 1.
Caused by error in `formula.character()`:
! invalid formula "total_info_inst_org_plan": not a call
Backtrace:
  1. tibble::data_frame(...)
  5. purrr::map(.x = formula, .f = function(x) lm(x, data = index_articles))
  6. purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 10. .f(.x[[i]], ...)
 15. stats::model.frame.default(...)
 16. stats::as.formula(formula)
 18. stats:::formula.character(object, env = baseenv())
 19. base::stop(...)
```

stargazer(regression$model, type = 'text')

Thank you!!!

Comment: do `y <- as.matrix(index_articles[elscincarticles]); x <- index_articles[, group_var]; lm(y~x)`

Comment: Thank you @onyambu how can I transform it to stargazer?